# Test JSON object contains the attributes I expect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing a simple `nodejs` express route that POST's a JSON object.

As a bit of a node/js newbie, I am curious to know if there is an elegant way of testing that a JSON object contains all the attributes that I expect to be submitted and only those attributes?

e.g. if i have a `JSON` object like this:

```
data:{
   "a":"somevalue".
   "b":"somebvalue",
   "c":"somecvalue"
}
```

I was thinking I could do something like:

```
if( (data.a) && (data.b) && (data.c) ){
   //Proceed and process post
else {
  // respond with unacceptable 
}
```

Am just wondering if there is a better way, either in JavaScript or express?

Comment: You mean JavaScript object, right? JSON is a way to serialize those.

Comment: `JSON.parse` is the way...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not completely correct for what you're doing. For example for the possible valid object `{a:undefined,b:3,c:5}` you'd think it does not have the required attributes but in fact it does. A more correct way (assuming the prototype is also fine) would be:

```
("a" in data) && ("b" in data) && ("c" in data)
```

If you'd like a solution that scales nicely for multiple properties:

You can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
if(["a","b","c"].every(function(attr){ return attr in data;})){
```

It's not shorter, but I'd argue it's more semantic, and it doesn't return false positive for empty strings, null and other 'falsy' values. Of course - you can extract this into a function :)

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L34TL/)

Comment: Also, you could move that function into it's own definition. `var propExistsInObject = function(){}` that way it reads like `if (['a','b','c'].every(propExistsInObject))`.

Comment: @JonJaques Yeah, that's a nice touch :)

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. I've adopted the above approach and built a function that takes in a test array and test object.#